# Commerce 3: Apply discount only to additional items

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, discounts

I have a product where I want to charge the full price ($300) for the first one, and then a discounted amount ($50) for each additional one.

So if a customer orders one, the cost is $300. Two would be $350. Three would be $400, etc.

I know I can set a discount that applies to all items, but is there a way to only apply it after the first?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [adjuster](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/extend/adjusters.html#writing-an-adjuster) to your logic via a module/plugin:

And the main body of your adjuster should look like this (if I correctly read your logic):

```
<?php

namespace modules\mymodule\adjusters;

use craft;
use craft\base\Component;
use craft\commerce\base\AdjusterInterface;
use craft\commerce\elements\Order;
use craft\commerce\models\OrderAdjustment;

class CustomAdjuster extends Component implements AdjusterInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Order $order
     *
     * @return array|OrderAdjustment[]
     */
    public function adjust(Order $order): array
    {
        $adjustments = [];

        $lineItems = $order->getLineItems();

        foreach ($lineItems as $i => $item) {
            // First product? Skip it
            if (0 === $i) {
                continue;
            }
            
            $adjustment = new OrderAdjustment();
            $adjustment->type = 'discount';
            $adjustment->name = "My 50$ discount";
            $adjustment->description = "My 50$ discount";
            // `sourceSnapshot` can contain information to explain the adjustment
            $adjustment->sourceSnapshot = [ 'data' => 'value' ];
            $adjustment->amount = 50;
            $adjustment->setOrder($order);
            $adjustment->setLineItem($item);
            $adjustments[] = $adjustment;
        }

        return $adjustments;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will discount everything in my cart after the first item, but I need it to only apply to a certain product variant.

The logic needs to be along the lines of if product id = 50, and quantity is > 1, then apply the discount to everything after the first.